# Site jumping instead of scrolling on first click

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am a noob on coding. I built my site using a template and modified it with Dreamweaver.
Everything is ok to me except one thing. When the page first loads my first click on anything jumps to that section instead of scrolling to it.

I spent a lot of time reading stuff and testing but still don't have a clue how to avoid it. My site is set to go "[Dreamscradle.com](http://Dreamscradle.com)" and I think think it should start with "[Dreamscradle.com/index.html](http://Dreamscradle.com/index.html)" How do I set it?
Any help will be welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you enter the site without `index.html` when clicking a link it will redirect to `index.html` and then add the anchor. You could rewrite your links without `index.html` to solve the issue.

for example:

```
 <a href="index.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
```

To:

```
 <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same. They keep appearing with **index.html#portfolio**. There isn't a way to set the site to start with DreamsCradle.com/index.html instead of just dreamscradle.com?